# mechanicalsoup TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, mechanicalsoup

I've read the previous posts here on the subject problem, although not specifically for mechanicalsoup, which mostly indicated a possible conflict between the module and class name, but I don't see how that would apply here.

I created a .py text file with two lines:
Also tried `from mechanicalsoup import mechanicalsoup` which resulted in an error. 
In case it is helpful, this is the output from print(mechanicalsoup):
module `mechanicalsoup` from

> 'C:\Users\peterk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mechanicalsoup\__init__.py'

```
import mechanicalsoup
browser=mechanicalsoup.stateful_browser()
```

When run, the output is:

> C:\Temp>bf.py
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Temp\bf.py", line 2, in
>
> ```
> browser=mechanicalsoup.stateful_browser()
> ```
>
> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: You probably meant: `mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser() `

Comment: Thanks, but nope: AttributeError: module 'mechanicalsoup' has no attribute 'statefulbrowser'

Comment: It is "StatefulBowser" not 'statefulbrowser'

Comment: Hint: if you're not sure about the spelling, copy-paste from documentation and/or examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to help you out. Firstly install latest ***mechanicalsoup*** by following this [LINK](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html#installation)

Then try this.

```
import mechanicalsoup

browser=mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.open("http://httpbin.org/")
```

And if you want to use ***stateful_browser*** use it like

```
browser=mechanicalsoup.stateful_browser
```

But it has no attribute ***open*** which is actually your aim. That is why use the **StatefulBrowser** as mentioned in their [documentation](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mechanicalsoup.html)